# SQL Like/Contains on BIGINT Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a BIGINT column that I want to do a partial match on.

e.g. `@search = 1` should return all records where the first number is 1 (1, 11, 100 etc). Basically the same as a varchar LIKE.

I have tried:

```
DECLARE @search VARCHAR
SET @search = '1'
```

and

```
SET @search = '1%'
```

And used:

```
SELECT
    id FROM table
WHERE
    CAST(id AS varchar) LIKE @search
```

Adding a `%` to `@search` doesn't help. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

EDIT: it seems to be the variable. If I hard code the string in the `WHERE` clause I get the results I am looking for.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE CAST(id AS VARCHAR) LIKE '14%'
```

This gives me all records with an `id` of 14* (14, 140, 1400 etc).

Comment: can you post your code with the '%' added?

Comment: Added more detail. Apologies, should have had it from the start.

Comment: What results do you get when you just Select CAST(id as Varchar) FROM table?

Comment: @NickBailey I get all the results from the table.

Comment: Well yes, of course, in what format?

Comment: @NickBailey sorry, it's just an unnamed column with all the IDs. I assume they are varchars, but SSMS doesn't really show much more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @search VARCHAR(10)
SET @search = '1'

SELECT id FROM table WHERE CAST(id AS VARCHAR(10)) LIKE @search + '%'
```

When casting to `VARCHAR`, you should always specify the length. If you don't define a length, SQL-Server will assign one for you. Sometimes it will be `1` others it will be `30`.  Read [**this**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works for @search = '1' but when I use `@search = '14' I still get 1, 10, 11 etc. Any ideas?

Comment: See my edit. You have to specify a length in your declaration.

Comment: As I commented on a similar answer, SQL isn't my forte. When I declare a size for the search term it does indeed work. Thank you so much for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the `LIKE` operator try using the [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) function. This will return the left part of a character string with the specified number of characters.

```
SELECT id 
FROM table
WHERE LEFT(CAST(id AS varchar), 1) = '1'
```

I'm not certain, but I've got to assume this is will have better performance than using the `LIKE` operator, especially since you know you just want to compare to the beginning characters. Often using a function in the WHERE clause can often cause poor performance because the query can't take advantage of any indexes that might exist on the column. However in this case the query calling the CAST function, so the benefit of the index is already lost.

**Edit:** If the comparison needs to be for a variable number of digits, then you can use the LEN function to determine the number of characters for the LEFT function to return.

```
SELECT id 
FROM table
WHERE LEFT(CAST(id AS varchar),LEN(@search)) = @search
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The search term will come from user input, so the length will be as long as the string they supply from the front end. I could get a length of the string and use that, though. Good alternative answer.

Comment: We are pushed for time for this release, but I will run some performance stats on this vs accepted answer next week.

Comment: I'd be interested to know your results if you do get a chance to evaluate the performance of the two approaches. Often using a function in the WHERE clause can often cause poor performance because the query can't take advantage of any indexes that might exist on the column. However, in this case the query is casting the column to an varchar, so the benefit of the index is already lost.

Answer (score 3):

Not a like but should do it. Replace x with id.

```
WHERE
(x >= 1000000000000000000 AND x < 2000000000000000000) OR
(x >= 100000000000000000 AND x < 200000000000000000) OR
(x >= 10000000000000000 AND x < 20000000000000000) OR
(x >= 1000000000000000 AND x < 2000000000000000) OR
(x >= 100000000000000 AND x < 200000000000000) OR
(x >= 10000000000000 AND x < 20000000000000) OR
(x >= 1000000000000 AND x < 2000000000000) OR
(x >= 100000000000 AND x < 200000000000) OR
(x >= 10000000000 AND x < 20000000000) OR
(x >= 1000000000 AND x < 2000000000) OR
(x >= 100000000 AND x < 200000000) OR
(x >= 10000000 AND x < 20000000) OR
(x >= 1000000 AND x < 2000000) OR
(x >= 100000 AND x < 200000) OR
(x >= 10000 AND x < 20000) OR
(x >= 1000 AND x < 2000) OR
(x >= 100 AND x < 200) OR
(x >= 10 AND x < 20) OR
(x = 1)
```

Comment: I'm guessing this will have better performance than the `CAST` based solutions since an index can be used (if it exists). The `CAST` solutions will have to cast on every BIGINT row in order to evaluate the predicate.

Comment: ...and it's a nice piece of ascii art to boot!

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with your `@search`. Try like below instead

```
create table aaa (id bigint);
insert into aaa values(1),(11),(100),(111),(1111),(2222);
```

Select Query

```
SELECT
    id FROM aaa
WHERE
    CAST(id AS varchar(1000)) LIKE '1%';
```

(OR) like below

```
DECLARE @search VARCHAR;
SET @search = '1';

SELECT
    id FROM aaa
WHERE
    CAST(id AS varchar(1000)) LIKE @search + '%';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works for `@search = '1'` but when I use `@search = '14' I still get 1, 10, 11 etc. Any ideas?

Comment: that's because of the line `DECLARE @search VARCHAR;` without any size specification it's always taking first character which is 1 in this case.

Comment: I see. SQL isn't my forte, so these kinds of gotchas always catch me out. When I declare the size it does indeed work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this without converting to `VARCHAR(30)` - but I did not test it to see if the performance is actually better.  `LOG10()` isn't cheap, but integer division is.  So testing is warranted.

Given:

```
create table aaa (id bigint);
insert into aaa values(1),(11),(100),(111),(1111),(2222),(1234),(4531),(1345134),(64513),(6451999123);

declare @want int = 64  -- and these are your starting digits
```

The crazy math:

```
select id 
from dbo.aaa
WHERE id / (CASE WHEN (LOG10(id) -CEILING(LOG10(@want))) > 1 
    THEN POWER(10 , CEILING(log10(id-1)-CEILING(LOG10(@want))) ) 
    ELSE 1 END)   = @want;
```

Basically, the pair of `LOG10()` determines the number of digits to shift right (via integer division) so that only the desired number of digits remain.

Comment: Wow. That sort of maths hurts my head! Interesting solution, though, very novel.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

`like 1%` is equivalent to: anything greater or Equal to 10, if you are comparing numeric.
So, you may want do similar to following:

```
SELECT
  id FROM table
WHERE
  id >= @search*10 --@Search is of course int
```

Comment: the query in the OP is using the `LIKE` operator to compare with the string `'1%'`.  The `%` character is a wild card in SQL Server.

Comment: I know what `like` is , I was trying not have it `cast` `int` to `varchar`, The comparison would be very poor in performance. It won't use any `indexes` either.

Comment: Oops. I was thinking something else, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this will give me any IDs greater than 10. I need only IDs that start with 1 (or whatever `@search` happens to be).